# Pointer - How to complete the function, fixing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, linked-list

Could anyone tell me what the problem is in my code? The main is provided and guaranteed to be correct, I only need to complete the function, to add a new patch to bottom.

**Definitions of Patch and Line:**

```
struct Line
{
    string data;
    Line *next;
};

struct Patch
{
    int x, y;    // to be used in other tasks, not related
    Line *head;
    Line *tail;
};
```

**To understand the structure better:**
[image]

The following is what I tried:

```
void append_to_bottom(Patch *patch, Line *line) {
    patch->tail->next = line;
    patch->tail = line;
    line->next = nullptr;
}
```

It reports "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x18)", what does it mean?

Comment: When you call `append_to_bottom`, are `patch` and `line` both pointing to an actual object? Is `patch`'s `tail` pointer valid?

Comment: @jkb Yes it is valid.

Comment: @ipinlnd My idea is, 1. Link the old tail to the line; 2. make ```line->next``` point to nullptr, since it now should be the last line; 3.update the patch's tail to line.

Comment: @keanehui yes sorry it was a dumb question. i realized before you answered -_-

Comment: You're dereferencing a null pointer somewhere, it's difficult to tell more without a [mre]. Have you tried debugging?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes I'm trying. Do you mean my function is correct? Since the whole programme is huge and it runs well as long as I comment out this function body, so I cannot quite find which line the problem is.

Comment: If you run under a debugger it should show you exactly where it is crashing and you can inspect the variables to find the one that is null

Comment: @AlanBirtles I'm using Xcode could you tell me how to display the error line? I just double click the error and it jumps to the first line of my function body with message EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: if you hover the mouse over patch it should show you the values either `patch` or `patch->tail` are null, probably `patch->tail` given the offset given